# angularjs email directive with different value for display and model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, email-validation

i have requirement where i can have a predefined suffix for email, so user just has to enter the first part of the email... so lets say my email id is: abc@gmail.com

so the input would have suffix of gmail.com and user should have to enter only "abc".
so what i want to achieve is: for display value should be abc, but for ngModel value should be "abc@gmail.com".

how can i achieve this using directives??

i have basic directive ready:[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5lqWgwX3jnwgC3JhnX2u?p=preview)

but not sure how to use, link or compile function to achieve above result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is using [$parsers and $formatter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

Try this directive:

```
app.directive("csRadioFieldFormat", function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',

    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctr) {
      ctr.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {

        var isValid = value !== "";

        ctr.$setValidity("required", isValid);
        if (!isValid){
          return undefined;
        }

        if (value.indexOf(attrs.suffix) < 0) {
          value = value + attrs.suffix;
        }

        return value;
      });

      ctr.$formatters.unshift(function(value) {
        value = value || "";
        return value.replace(attrs.suffix, "");
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Apply it to your email field:

```
<input type="email" name="myfield" ng-required="options.required" ng-model="ngModel" cs-radio-field-format suffix="{{options.suffix}}"/>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ALHll7cWhE3edoaItbUN?p=preview)

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, its exactly working as expected... just one more question: why is the bootstrap styling still showing the  field as invalid(red). i think <input type="email" /> is the problem. but i can not make type=text or if i do make type=text then i will have to use the pattern for email validation.. whats the best way out of this?

Comment: can you look at this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/2Bn8Pqm8umMXTb4Um6mY?p=preview for some reason the parser is not getting invoked...

Comment: @HarishR: for the styling, it's a css problem. Some rules like `input:focus:invalid` apply based on the current value in the DOM, it's browser behavior. I don't know a way to get around this problem when we use `type="email"`

Comment: @HarishR: the directive with `$parsers` must be applied directly to the `<input type="number">`. In your case, your add parsers inside `csNumberField`, it does not apply to `<input type="number">` in your directive's template.

Comment: @HarishR: for the `type="email"` problem. I think you have to validate the field manually and add a class to the input => then style the input based on its class

Comment: ok got it.. so mostly i would need to write a custom validator, which will validate the value with the suffix provided...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48269/discussion-between-harishr-and-khanh-to)